# How to search the word after the specific line in the file in linux?

Tags: grep

I have a file with 100 lines and i have to search the word happy but the search must start after the 50th line of the file.
what's the exact grep command is used in linux?

Answer (score 3):

You could also use `head` + `grep` and group the commands with `{...}` to share the same input:

```
{ head -n 50 >/dev/null; grep PATTERN; } <infile
```

that way `head` gets only the first `n` lines, dumps them to `/dev/null` and the remaining lines are processed by `grep`.

Answer (score 2):

Use `tail` to get the contents of the file from line 51 onwards, and then `grep` that. Use `-i` to ignore case (so you also match "Happy", "HAPPY", etc) and a space before to match only "happy" and not any other words that contain that sequence of letters.

```
tail -n +51 filename.txt | grep -i " happy"
```

Comment: +1, but note that the word "happy" might have parentheses or quotes around it or it might be followed by any of `,``.``;` etc or it might be at the beginning/end of line; also since the search must start after the 50th line you could `tail -n +51`

Comment: Good points. Edited accordingly.

Comment: I think you could just `grep pattern`. The question is about how to `grep` after a certain line and IMO the _word_ problem is beyond the scope of this question (and it most likely has been already addressed on this site). Up to you though.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a `sed` way to get from 50th line to the end of the file and then using `grep` to search for the pattern:

```
sed -n '50,$p' file.txt | grep "happy"
```

Or just using `sed` to do it altogether:

```
sed -n '50,$s/happy/&/p' file.txt
```

Here are few more `sed` ways (Thanks to 'Stéphane Chazelas'):

```
sed '50,$!d;/happy/!d' file.txt
sed -n '50,${/happy/p;}' file.txt
```

Comment: Why not just search with sed, while you are at it?

Comment: @orion: Good point..answer edited

Comment: Or `sed '50,$!d;/happy/!d'` or `sed -n '50,${/happy/p;}'`

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas: Thanks, i have added these too..

Answer (score 0):

You will need `awk`:

```
awk 'NR>50' filename.txt | grep '\bhappy\b'
```

Comment: That's wrong. You got it backwards. "NR>50" makes no sense *after* you already grepped out only the lines that contain the word `happy`. It's also a good idea to use word boundaries to avoid matching partial words (this version also matches `unhappy` which is probably not what you want).

Comment: You are right. Corrected.

Comment: That only matches cases when the word is alone in the line. I meant `\bhappy\b`. At least in GNU grep. And `cat` is unnecessary. Just give the file to `awk`.

Comment: @orion, `grep -w happy` may be slightly more portable than `\b`. Neither is standard. The GNU one doesn't work in multi-byte locales (`grep -w phane` or `grep '\bphane\b'` match on `Stéphane` for instance).